# How does activity get data from running service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity

I have a running service that suppose to store location data.

at a certain moment, in the activity layout, I want to get data from the service.

how can I do that?

thanks,

Yoni

Comment: You can look into content providers. The service can commit data to a database when it runs, through the content provider, and the activity can then use the content provider to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a Handler that will pass message from the `Service` to the `Activity`
use the example at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

go to **Remote Messenger Service Sample**